# My app supports no device

Tags: google-play, android-manifest

I've got a big problem with my first app. I've uploaded the app earlier this day to the Google Play Store and there it says that my app supports zero devices. What am I doing wrong? Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="true"   />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
    android:required="true">
</uses-feature>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="app.wallpaper.com.giflivewallpaper.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="app.wallpaper.com.giflivewallpaper.GIFWallpaperService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="Particle Live Wallpaper"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" >
        </meta-data>
    </service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `uses-feature`, did you mean `android.software.live_wallpaper`?

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper"
    android:required="true">
</uses-feature>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html